# App not archiving in Xcode v14.1 (14B47b)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not able to archive app in Xcode 14.1 and above.

It keeps asking me to add development team to one of my pods [CleverTap-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-ios-sdk) v4.1.1

[image]

I tried archiving the same code in older Xcode (13 and below) and it is working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Just select your team in the “Team” drop down menu about 1/3 down and centered on the screenshot.

Comment: In older Xcode it is running without team. Shall we add tea for pod also?

Comment: This might help, it worked for me https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11196